# Do something with the numerous line number tags

Tags: support, tags

There are three tags that refer to the same thing.

1. [line-number](/questions/tagged/line-number)
2. [line-numbers](/questions/tagged/line-numbers)
3. [line-numbering](/questions/tagged/line-numbering)

Now, I'm not sure what we should do with these. We could merge them all into one tag; which, if we did, I vote for [line-numbers](/questions/tagged/line-numbers) purely because it has 96 tagged questions compared to 9 and 10 for [line-number](/questions/tagged/line-number) and [line-numbering](/questions/tagged/line-numbering) respectively. Community?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see none and one in [line-number](/questions/tagged/line-number) and [line-numbering](/questions/tagged/line-numbering) respectively.

I removed the offending tag from the one question.

I personally don't think we need a synonym for this, though there's no harm in doing so... IMO, if there are like 20 questions in a tag, you can retag them yourself :)

Comment: Coolio. I was just feeling lazy and wanted to play with Legos! =D